# display value from database in select input and radio

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, crud

I'm a beginner in laravel and i created an ajax crud in my project, i want to use in my editing form the input types select and radio, but i don't know how to implement it,can you help me please.

This is my edit button:

```
 <button 
    class="edit-modal btn btn-info" 
    data-id="{{$dechet->id}}" 
    data-type="{{$dechet->type}}" 
    data-description="{{$dechet->description}}" 
    data-statut="{{$dechet->statut}}" 
    data-utilisateur="{{$dechet->utilisateur}}" 
    data-heure="{{$dechet->heure}}">
       <span class="icon-pencil"></span>
 </button>
```

and this is my edit form:

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="id">ID:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
              <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control"
               id="id_edit" disabled>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="date">Date: 
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <input type="datetime" name="date" class="form-control"
                id="date_edit">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-3"
            for="utilisateur">utilisateur:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <input type="text" name="utilisateur" class="form-
                 control" id="utilisateur_edit" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="type">Type:
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">   
                <select name="type" class="select" id="type_edit">
                   <option value="" {{ $dechet->type == '' ? 
                   'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{ $dechet->type}}
                   </option>                                        
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="statut">Statut:
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">                                      
                <label class="radio-inline">
                     <input type="radio" class="styled" name="statut"
                     id="statut_edit" value="0" {{ $dechet->statut == '0'
                     ? 'checked' : '' }}>Refusée </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                     <input type="radio" class="styled" name="statut"
                     id="statut_edit" value="1" {{ $dechet->statut == '1'
                     ? 'checked' : '' }}>En cours</label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" class="styled" name="statut"
                    id="statut_edit" value="2"{{ $dechet->statut == '2' ?
                    'checked' : '' }}>Acceptée</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-3"  
            for="description">Description:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="description"
                id="description_edit" rows="5" cols="5"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

ajax call:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-modal', function() {
        $('.modal-title').text('Edit');
        $('#id_edit').val($(this).data('id'));
        $('#type_edit').val($(this).data('type'));
        $('#description_edit').val($(this).data('description'));
        $('#date_edit').val($(this).data('heure'));
        $('#utilisateur_edit').val($(this).data('utilisateur'));
        $('#statut_edit').val($(this).data('statut'));
        id = $('#id_edit').val();
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
    });
$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.edit', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: 'updateDechets' + id,
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'id': $("#id_edit").val(),
                'type': $('#type_edit').val(),
                'statut': $('#statut_edit').val(),
                'description': $('#description_edit').val(),
                'date': $('#date_edit').val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('.errorType').addClass('hidden');
                $('.errorStatut').addClass('hidden');
                $('.errorDescription').addClass('hidden');
                $('.errorDate').addClass('hidden');

                if ((data.errors)) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#editModal').modal('show');
                    toastr.error('Validation error!', 'Error Alert',
                    {timeOut: 5000});}, 500);

                if (data.errors.type) {
                        $('.errorType').removeClass('hidden');
                        $('.errorType').text(data.errors.type);
                    }
                if (data.errors.statut) {
                        $('.errorStatut').removeClass('hidden');
                        $('.errorStatut').text(data.errors.statut);
                    }
                if (data.errors.description) {
                        $('.errorDescription').removeClass('hidden');
                  $('.errorDescription').text(data.errors.description);
                    }
                if (data.errors.date) {
                        $('.errorDate').removeClass('hidden');
                        $('.errorDate').text(data.errors.date);
                    }
                } else {
                    toastr.success('Successfully updated dechet!',
                    'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                }
            }
        });
    });
```